# System Freezes seemingly randomly (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, firefox, ram, youtube

I experienced some more or less random system freezes (or near freezes) while working. I have Firefox playing music in the background while working in Atom and everything is going well up until when the audio starts stuttering and the system responds only every few seconds.
Killing the Youtube Tab usually works to resolve it but sometimes it is hard getting there in the first place due to unresponsiveness. This does not happen every time. It might have to do with the length of the video as I tend to listen to longer (>1h) music videos or audio books.

I had htop running the last time it happened and checked there every few minutes. It looked fine even a couple of seconds before it started again. When I checked then, the system memory and swap was completely filled. As usual, killing Youtube helped. I only had 2 other tabs open, the terminal and telegram.

Weird thing is, this only happens on a particular laptop (I have Ubuntu installed on an external harddrive). The other one runs Firefox and Youtube videos just fine. The laptop where the problem happens has an Nvidia graphics card and I have trouble with my Wifi card occasionally. Not too long ago I had a 70GB kern.log filled in one day which might be related to one of these.

Could it be related to the graphics card drivers? How can I investigate the issue further? And more importantly, what could I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

try removing all firefox add-ons and plugins. For me it turned out to be dark reader.

Comment: In a slightly unrelated note, did you by any chance accidentally install the malicious [malware clone of Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/blog/attention/) instead of the real one?

Comment: I never considered that.  However the one I had installed had been working for a couple of years before it started acting up.  So doesn't discount that possibility!