# System freezes on Ubuntu 20.04 and WiFi stops working

Tags: gnome, video, kde, radeon

I suddenly started facing an odd issue a few days ago which seems to happen only sometimes. If I'm streaming video or even doing an audio call on a browser (Chrome or Firefox), my system sometimes freezes completely and the last half second or so of the audio plays on loop. I have to do a hard shut down by long pressing the power button. The last time this happened, I foung the syslog entries immediately preceeding this:

```
May 12 15:15:22 Machine gnome-shell[12407]: [19904:20:0512/151522.107395:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3350)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
May 12 15:15:44 Machine gnome-shell[12407]: [19904:20:0512/151544.534097:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3350)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
May 12 15:16:08 Machine gnome-shell[2103]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
May 12 15:16:29 Machine gnome-shell[2103]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
May 12 15:17:01 Machine CRON[20644]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 12 15:17:34 Machine gnome-shell[12407]: [19904:20:0512/151734.483733:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3350)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
May 12 15:19:21 Machine gnome-shell[12407]: [19904:20:0512/151921.527291:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3350)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
May 12 15:20:08 Machine gnome-shell[12407]: [19904:20:0512/152008.433602:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3350)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
May 12 15:20:55 Machine gnome-shell[2103]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
May 12 15:24:32 Machine kernel: [12112.697501] perf: interrupt took too long (3145 > 3126), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
May 12 15:26:18 Machine gnome-shell[2103]: message repeated 3 times: [ ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.]
May 12 15:30:01 Machine CRON[20950]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
```

Not sure if it's related, but my system is also freezing occasionally when I close the lid. And the problems I've had are quite similar to those in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193978/system-freezes-seemingly-randomly-ubuntu-18-04). I also have a dedicated AMD Radeon GPU besides the integrated Intel one and I also once had a problem with my WiFi. I faced the huge system log problems before fixing that to ensure syslog files never get that huge. But the only problem is that since my system freezes completely I don't have a chance to see whether my RAM and Swap have been completely filled up or not. And the solution given isn't applicable to me.

In case it's relevant, I recently faced [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333195/screen-flickering-on-ubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2274623_1333195) problem due to the bad 5.8.0-50 kernel upgrade, which I resolved by going back to the 5.8.0-43 kernel.

UPDATE: There still is no solution and the occasional system freeze keeps happening. I can't find a common occurrence because it has sometimes happened even when nothing was being streamed. It has happened three times when Firefox was running and once when Chrome was. Also, I have KDE Plasma alongside GNOME and the problem clearly seems more frequent on KDE Plasma. And there is some connection with my WiFi perhaps because now it has happened twice that after doing a hard reboot after the freeze, the WiFi hasn't worked. I have a dual boot and booting into Windows and then back into Ubuntu fixes the WiFi.

UPDATE: Decided to go back to an older kernel on a hunch and it was fine for a day or two but the problem isn't gone. It still happens and running video definitely has something to do with it because it rarely ever happens unless a video is playing. There's zilch in the system log that indicates an issue.

UPDATE: Just faced multiple crashes over a short period of time. Shortly before one of them, WiFi stopped working in the middle of a session (this time the system rebooted on its own). Here are the logs:

```
May 28 13:13:04 Machine wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.206213] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:05 Machine wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=d8:32:14:ac:c3:51 reason=4 locally_generated=1
May 28 13:13:05 Machine NetworkManager[1080]: <warn> [1622187785.4714] sup-iface[0x5643f88e0120,wlp8s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.386690] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.386692] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:05 Machine wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
May 28 13:13:05 Machine NetworkManager[1080]: <info> [1622187785.5013] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 28 13:13:05 Machine NetworkManager[1080]: <info> [1622187785.5014] device (p2p-dev-wlp8s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.499354] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:05 Machine NetworkManager[1080]: <info> [1622187785.7671] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 28 13:13:05 Machine NetworkManager[1080]: <info> [1622187785.7671] device (p2p-dev-wlp8s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.682440] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.682444] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.694287] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.875265] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.875269] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:05 Machine kernel: [ 382.886876] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.067340] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.067343] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.078891] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.259781] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.259786] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.271428] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.452775] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.452779] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.464488] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:06 Machine gnome-shell[2785]: [2778:2903:0528/131306.670523:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(429 )] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.645343] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.645349] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.656982] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.837653] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.837655] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:06 Machine kernel: [ 383.849256] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.029730] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.029732] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.041264] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.221517] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.221520] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.233066] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.413455] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.413457] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.425027] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.606230] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.606234] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.617913] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.827768] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.827772] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:07 Machine kernel: [ 384.839466] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.021760] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.021764] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.033343] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.214743] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.214748] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.226332] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.408193] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.408198] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.419929] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.602564] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.602568] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.614334] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.796999] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.797003] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:08 Machine kernel: [ 385.808712] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 385.989881] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 385.989885] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.001417] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.181595] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.181598] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.193159] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.373430] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.373433] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.385040] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.566223] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.566227] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.577874] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.759163] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.759167] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:09 Machine kernel: [ 386.770887] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 386.953264] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 386.953268] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 386.965018] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.146871] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.146875] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.158537] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.366195] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.366199] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.377851] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.560208] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.560213] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.571827] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.753678] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.753682] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:10 Machine kernel: [ 387.765389] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 387.947248] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 387.947252] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 387.958835] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.139488] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.139492] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.151087] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.331842] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.331847] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.343403] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.524071] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.524076] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.535694] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.716655] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.716660] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.728373] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.909853] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:11 Machine kernel: [ 388.909857] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 388.921631] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.103311] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.103315] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.114925] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.296130] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.296134] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.307803] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.488445] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.488449] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.500061] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.681076] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.681080] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.692809] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.874830] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.874844] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:12 Machine kernel: [ 389.886718] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:13 Machine kernel: [ 390.068907] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:13 Machine kernel: [ 390.068912] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:13 Machine kernel: [ 390.080601] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
May 28 13:13:13 Machine kernel: [ 390.262758] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
May 28 13:13:13 Machine kernel: [ 390.262762] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
May 28 13:13:13 Machine kernel: [ 390.274446] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
```

I suspect system overheating has something to do with it because the last one happened just as I logged in (the desktop screen hadn't even loaded). I let the laptop be off for 20 minutes and then started it and it hasn't crashed so far. Here is another log entry before the crash in case it helps pinpoint the source.

```
May 28 13:20:17 Machine gnome-shell[3664]: libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
May 28 13:20:18 Machine gnome-shell[3664]: [3704:3704:0528/132018.336942:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

And this one from a few minutes after that:

```
May 28 13:27:04 Machine systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
May 28 13:27:04 Machine gnome-session-binary[1482]: Entering running state
May 28 13:27:04 Machine gsd-media-keys[1852]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settingslayback-repeat
May 28 13:27:04 Machine gsd-media-keys[1852]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:rfkill
May 28 13:27:04 Machine gsd-media-keys[1852]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
May 28 13:27:04 Machine gsd-media-keys[1852]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settingslayback-random
May 28 13:27:04 Machine dbus-daemon[1100]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ColorManager'
May 28 13:27:04 Machine systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
May 28 13:27:04 Machine xbrlapi.desktop[2027]: openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
May 28 13:27:04 Machine xbrlapi.desktop[2027]: cannot connect to braille devices daemon brltty at :0
May 28 13:27:05 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2034]: The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
May 28 13:27:05 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2034]: > Warning: Unsupported maximum keycode 569, clipping.
May 28 13:27:05 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2034]: > X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
May 28 13:27:05 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2034]: > Internal error: Could not resolve keysym Invalid
May 28 13:27:05 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2034]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 28 13:27:07 Machine gnome-shell[1542]: Warning: Failed to start gsd-xsettings
May 28 13:27:08 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1542]: libinput error: client bug: timer event5 keyboard: scheduled expiry is in the past (-74ms), your system is too slow
May 28 13:27:08 Machine gnome-shell[1542]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js 24]: reference to undefined property "MetaWindowXwayland"
```

UPDATE: Despite reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 (with a kernel upgrade to 5.8.0-53), this issue persists. Reinstalled yesterday, had the first system freeze today after I opened the laptop lid and opened a couple of tabs on Chrome (the browser was already open). I don't know what the hell is going on and why no can seem to help with this.

UPDATE: A little while ago I'd shut the laptop lid (my system is not set to suspend if that happens). I opened it to find that it was restarting on its own. I found the following log entries from around that time:

```
Jun  2 18:15:49 Machine thermald[849]: sensor id 4 : No temp sysfs for reading raw tempJun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.336014] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.110 seconds) done.
Jun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.446664] OOM killer disabled.
Jun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.446667] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.448174] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.599021] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.685897] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.930059] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
Jun  2 18:23:11 Machine kernel: [   51.959324] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x00000000001D6000).
```

Another bunch of entries are these:

```
Jun  2 18:23:13 Machine thermald[849]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml"
Jun  2 18:23:13 Machine thermald[849]: error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
Jun  2 18:23:13 Machine thermald[849]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml"
Jun  2 18:23:13 Machine thermald[849]: error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
Jun  2 18:23:13 Machine thermald[849]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml"
Jun  2 18:23:13 Machine thermald[849]: error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
```

I've looked up this thermald error but I haven't been able to find any clearcut solutions to it that I can implement.

Is there any chance at all that having both Gnome and KDE Plasma installed is causing this? Especially since I've set gdm3 as the display manager rather than sddm?

UPDATE: There is STILL no solution to this and the issue hasn't gone away. I have noticed a few times that when I have around 5-6 Chrome tabs (which I used to have earlier as well) with possibly heavier websites, my memory is over 90% full and the system becomes jittery. But still can't be sure if this is the root cause (why doesn't syslog mention anything about this?). I also don't understand how my Windows install is fine with the 4 GB RAM I have but Ubuntu isn't. Here is another log entry after the most recent crash:

```
Jul  4 14:25:48 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
Jul  4 14:25:48 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26685:26685:0704/142548.700456:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Jul  4 14:25:53 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26646:26666:0704/142553.812893:ERROR:gcm_store_impl.cc(652)] LevelDB remove failed: NotFound:
Jul  4 14:25:53 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26646:26669:0704/142553.813045:ERROR:mcs_client.cc(526)] GCM Update failed!
Jul  4 14:27:18 Machine PackageKit: daemon quit
Jul  4 14:27:18 Machine systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Jul  4 14:27:56 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142756.708204:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:27:56 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142756.796603:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:27:56 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142756.852918:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:03 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142803.997212:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:04 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142804.080933:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:04 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142804.141079:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:14 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142814.603884:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:14 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142814.668010:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:14 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142814.780805:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:14 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142814.860787:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:17 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: (transmission-gtk:27230): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:28:17.210: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed
Jul  4 14:28:17 Machine dbus-daemon[852]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.212' (uid=1000 pid=27230 comm="transmission-gtk magnet:?xt=urn:btih:1EF2D24F1ECFF" label="unconfined")
Jul  4 14:28:17 Machine systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jul  4 14:28:18 Machine dbus-daemon[852]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jul  4 14:28:18 Machine systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jul  4 14:28:21 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142821.884753:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:21 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142821.964205:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:22 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142822.068246:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:22 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26687:26690:0704/142822.140346:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
Jul  4 14:28:32 Machine google-chrome.desktop[26653]: [26685:26685:0704/142832.102447:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(314)] [.RendererMainThread-0x2c11bcb84700] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
Jul  4 14:28:48 Machine systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
```

Honestly, I find it bizarre that no one has an answer to this despite providing so much information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `tlp` or `slimbook-battery`, uninstall them.

Comment: No, I'm not using either